# Discordjs token unavailable to the client

Tags: typescript, discord.js

I'm writing a bot in typescript with Discordjs to send a message to a specified channel. I'm getting the error

```
HTTPError [DiscordjsError]: Request to use token, but token was unavailable to the client.
```

I'm waiting for client to be ready before trying to send, I have checked the variables in .env, removed bot from server, created new application with new bot, redone OAuth2 and given it admin privileges and added again, client.token returns the value of DISCORD_TOKEN. What on earth am I missing?

code:

```
import { Client, TextChannel } from "discord.js";
import dotenv from "dotenv";
dotenv.config();

//get and check env vars present
const token = process.env.DISCORD_TOKEN;
if (!token) {
  throw new Error("provide DISCORD_TOKEN as env variable");
}
const channelId = process.env.DISCORD_CHANNEL_ID;
if (!channelId) {
  throw new Error("provide DISCORD_CHANNEL_ID as env variable");
}

//create and login discord client instance
const client = new Client({ intents: ["GUILDS", "GUILD_MESSAGES"] });
try{
  client.login(token)
} catch (err) {
  console.log(`problem on client login: ${err}`)
} 

//send notification
client.on("ready", async () => {
  console.log(client.isReady())
  console.log(client.token)
  console.log("discord client ready!");
  const channel = (await client.channels.fetch(channelId)) as TextChannel;
  channel.send('hello channel')
  client.destroy()
  console.log('done')
});
```

full output

```
rue
OT########################## //discord token
discord client ready!
done
/Users/.../node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RequestHandler.js:200
        throw new HTTPError(error.message, error.constructor.name, error.status, request);
              ^

HTTPError [DiscordjsError]: Request to use token, but token was unavailable to the client.
    at RequestHandler.execute (/Users/.../node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RequestHandler.js:200:15)
    at RequestHandler.execute (/Users/.../node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RequestHandler.js:204:19)
    at RequestHandler.push (/Users/.../node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RequestHandler.js:50:25)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async TextChannel.send (/Users/.../node_modules/discord.js/src/structures/interfaces/TextBasedChannel.js:172:15) {
  code: 500,
  method: 'post',
  path: '/channels/905578571374952478/messages',
  requestData: {
    json: {
      content: 'hello channel',
      tts: false,
      nonce: undefined,
      embeds: undefined,
      components: undefined,
      username: undefined,
      avatar_url: undefined,
      allowed_mentions: undefined,
      flags: undefined,
      message_reference: undefined,
      attachments: undefined,
      sticker_ids: undefined
    },
    files: []
  }
}
```

edits: logged client.token to show it exists when required and added full output

Comment: It means the token is used before login (or after destroy).

Comment: Can we know what was logged?

Comment: Thanks I have added,

Answer (score 0):

of course...

```
await channel.send('hello channel')
```

fixes it